# "Indicative", "Suggestive", and other alternatives

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am documenting a software design for a scheduling system. The system allows users to allocate tasks to people. The UI displays a list of people, alongside their pattern of working hours. Tasks can be allocated outside a person's working hours.

I am trying to decide on the most elegant way to express this rule.

So far I have a few alternatives:

1. "The working hours displayed are suggestive"
2. "The working hours displayed are a guide"
3. "The working hours displayed are not enforced"
4. "The working hours displayed are indicative"

I'm sure there is a more elegant word, but can't recall it at the moment.

Comment: "Advisory" was the word I couldn't recall. Feel free to post an answer

Comment: "Example working hours"?

Comment: Advisory? You are presenting a history of working patterns the point of which is to help an employer allocate tasks.  How is this an advisory?  It seems to me it's a tool showing behavior.  "Where is the advisory?"  Huh?   It's not something that would key me.  It's a representation of behavior.  A history of working hours.  jimm101 has it.  Don't obscure.

Comment: "The working hours are advisory". I am using advisory as an adjective: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/advisory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is ['advisory'](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/advisory?s=t)

> **Advisory** - adjective
>
> 1 - of, giving, or containing advice : 
>   *an advisory letter from a stockbroker.*
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Comment: Advisory is perfect. Your other suggestion of indicative would also be acceptable but I feel that Advisory flows better. With Indicative, it feels like something's missing; I find myself asking "indicative of what?"